# Debugging a Multithreaded Webserver in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, webserver

I'm developing a multithreaded webserver applet and have been dealing with system.out.println's for the past week or so as my "debugging" tool. As far as I understand it, the .jar I build is split by a builder and put into .html files and then spit out when I access the web server.

I am wondering if there is some way that I would be able to attach a debugger (plugin?) to Java's virtual machine that would allow me to step through the code as I operate the webserver- there are some critical exceptions that are very frustrating to track down. I believe they're timing issues related to the multithreading which makes them even more unreliable when attempting to locate, and may mean that the debugger won't process appropriately. I don't think it matters, but the IDE I'm building in is Netbeans.

I've taken over a previous developer's hastily-not-quite-finished project and am in well over my head. =/ Thanks in advance for any possible solutions, I appreciate it.

Comment: What's a webserver applet? Netbeans is capable of multithreaded debugging.

Comment: [This FAQ page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingAppletRemotely) was the first search result in Google for the search terms: debug applet netbeans. Not posting as answer as I'm not sure whether you want to perform multithreaded debugging of the server or simply remote debugging of applets.

Comment: Ah, multi-threading race conditions.  Oh the fun.  Look at the concurrent utils in Java 5+6 and learn how to use synchronized and transient.  This might come in very useful.

Comment: Thanks Vineet, but those steps aren't working for me as I'm not sure how I need to be starting the webserver in debug mode. The Java CP isn't accepting my runtime environment settings for some reason, and I believe that I need to start the webserver with the "-Xdebug" mode somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

You need to start the web server JVM with suitable arguments allowing it to be debugged remotely.  You can see at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jdb.html  how to do it.  jdb is available in the JDK along with javac.  You then launch your IDE debugger to connect to your JVM *and* tell it where the source for your classes is located.  Remember to compile with debug information.

As you have it inside Netbeans already then consider just launching it in debug mode as then all the extra work described above will be done automatically for you.

Comment: The debugger settings linked by Vineet in the comments don't seem to be working. Seems like a common problem with no resolution I've seen.

So it seems as if I'll try your longer solution. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to give a latent bump; do you have any idea how to allow the JVM to start with debugging allowed? I've modified the JRE Runtime Parameters but it's not saving them for some reason. A search online shows that it's a problem others have had before, with no given solutions.

If you have any further ideas I'd be happy to give them a try.

Comment: From within Netbeans?  Sorry, I do Eclipse.  Perhaps you want to open a question explicitly on this?